# Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'users.*' in 'field list'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mysql2

I'm seeing this error thrown for multiple tables. Searching StackOverflow it seems most peoples problems are related to a specific column missing but in my case it's trying to select everything ie. using "*".

Anyone have any insight?

```
Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'users.*' in 'field list'
```

**UPDATE**

From the rails log:

```
Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'users.*' in 'field list': SELECT  `users`.`*` FROM `users`  WHERE `users`.`id` = 53  ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
```

I figured out how to reproduce this locally or at least how I think it may be occurring:

```
2.1.2 :037 > client = Mysql2::Client.new(:host => "localhost", :username => "root",  :password => "root", :database => "development")
 => #<Mysql2::Client:0x007ff45b72dd30 @read_timeout=nil, @query_options={:as=>:hash, :async=>false, :cast_booleans=>false, :symbolize_keys=>false, :database_timezone=>:local, :application_timezone=>nil, :cache_rows=>true, :connect_flags=>2147525125, :cast=>true, :host=>"localhost", :username=>"root", :password=>"root", :database=>"development"}> 
2.1.2 :038 > result = client.query("SELECT `users`.`*` FROM `users` LIMIT 1")
Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'users.*' in 'field list'
    from (irb):40:in `query'
    from (irb):40
    from /Users/mark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
    from /Users/mark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /Users/mark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:69:in `console'
    from /Users/mark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
    from /Users/mark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

The query:

```
SELECT `users`.`*` FROM `users` LIMIT 1
```

fails when the special all selector * is wrapped in quotes.

```
SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` LIMIT 1
```

works without issue. Perhaps that is a MySQL thing? Regardless, these queries are generated by ActiveRecord / ActiveModel so perhaps I've found a bug.

Comment: Does that table exist in the db?

Comment: @japed Yes, there is a `users` table.

Comment: Can you post the full backtrace

Comment: @japed https://gist.github.com/MarkMurphy/3e8c34a0758959252c5e

Comment: Perhaps this is a query that should join 'users' but doesn't. You should provide a code example that demonstrates the error and any other gems u are using that might interact/modify with the mysql2 gem and active record. Sometimes I find it helpful to call .to_sql with  on an active record relation and print that to the log or 'puts' if I'm getting strange sql errors.

Comment: @joshmckin It's actually occurring on almost all tables and it's only occurring on my production server and not locally. It also seems to come and go...it's extremely odd.

Comment: If the table does exist, the only other possibility would be connection executing the query using different "schema/database" than that which users exists.

Comment: @joshmckin Definitely not the connection but see updated post for more details.

Comment: Mysql doesn't like \`*\`. What does User.limit(1).to_sql generate?

Comment: @joshmckin It generates: ``SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users`  LIMIT 1``

Comment: OK, then you need to find the query that is generating a bad select statement causing issues. If your logger is not writing all the statements to your log you can patch AR with 'puts sql' here: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-1-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb#L227 . Once you have the query start digging threw your code and any gems you are using that make DB calls to find what is generating the sql, because its definitely not vanilla AR or mysql2.

Comment: It could also be a bad "FROM" but you wont know until you get the entire query

Comment: I don't think it's the `FROM`. The one form the log above looks fine.

Comment: You need the sql statement from your app not the one from your example. Can you provide the dev log of your app including the sql statement that is called before the exception is thrown. It seems unlikely AR/Arel/mysql2 is generating \`*\`

Comment: @joshmckin I'm thinking it was Arel. This morning I tried the following from a rails console: ``users = User.arel_table
users.project(users[Arel.star]).to_sql
  => "SELECT `users`.`*` FROM `users`"``

Comment: Thats definitely odd. I cannot reproduce locally. I'd suggest updating to the latest version of rails 4.1 and Arel, and see if that helps.